# Does the following complex infinite series converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I'm currently tackling a homework problem that asks if the following series converges or diverges:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^n}{n+1} $$
Currently, I have attempted the ratio test to no avail, because I reach a final expression of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{i(n+1)}{n+2}$ which doesn't really help in determining convergence. Also, I have tried to think of similar series that could potentially be used to do a comparison test, but I can't think of anything that works. Any answers and explanations would be very useful and very appreciated!

Comment: Hint: look at the real and imaginary parts as separate series.

Comment: @dxiv can you clarify what exactly is the "real part" of this series? To me, the element of the series is strictly imaginary.

Comment: Write down the first few terms: $$\frac{1}{1} + \frac{i}{2}-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{i}{4}+ \frac{1}{5} + \cdots$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^n}{n+1}=\frac{1}{0+1}+\frac{i}{1+1}+\frac{-1}{2+1}+\frac{-i}{3+1}+\cdots$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}+i\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+2}$$
Do you recognize the first sum from anywhere? Maybe the [Leibnez Formula for $\pi$?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) What about the second sum? If we take a factor of $2$ out of the denominator, do you notice a [famous series for $\log(2)$?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm)

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
-\log(1-z)&=&\int\frac{1}{1-z}dz\\&=&\int\sum_1z^n\\&=&\sum_1\int z^n\\&=&\sum_1\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}\\&=&z\sum_1\frac{z^{n}}{n+1}\\&=&z\sum_0\frac{z^{n}}{n+1}-z
\end{eqnarray}
set $z=i$, we have $1+i\log(1-i)=\color{blue}{1+\dfrac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi+i\dfrac12\ln2}$.